# inequality with arc length integral

Tags: alternative-proof, integral-inequality

We have an inequality  such that
 $\int ^{\alpha }_{0}\sqrt {1+\cos ^{2}\left( t\right) }dt \geq \sqrt {\alpha^{2}+\sin ^{2}\alpha} $ 
over $ 0\leq \alpha \leq \dfrac {\pi }{2} $.

I have already proven it by considerations on the arc length of $x\to \sin(x)$, but I still wonder if there are another methods.

Comment: Methods other than what? We don't know your proof, so how can anyone give "other" methods?

Comment: by not using curvilinear integral

Comment: What is a *curvilinear integral*, by the way? Do you mean an integral representing an arc length? Or a contour integral? Also: the inequality *is not* strict if $\alpha=0$ (which is allowed).

Comment: yess,we are lectured that it is called as curvilinear my tonque is not actually english, also there is no  good word that express it in my language

Comment: @emreiris: yes to what? Arc length or contour integral? The former, I guess.

Comment: curvilinear integrals represent arc length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\alpha\in I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ the inequality
$$ \int_{0}^{\alpha}\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}\,dt \geq \sqrt{\alpha^2+\sin^2\alpha} $$
is trivial since the LHS is the arc length of $x\to \sin(x)$ over $J=(0,\alpha)\subset I$ and such function is concave over $I$. On the other hand, it is also pretty accurate: the difference $E(\alpha)$ between the LHS and the RHS is increasing over $I$, attaining its maximum at $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$ E\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0.0480030054\ldots$$
It can be improved through the same principle: for instance
$$ \int_{0}^{\alpha}\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}\,dt \geq\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{4}\alpha^2+\sin^2\tfrac{\alpha}{2}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{4}\alpha^2+\left(\sin\alpha-\sin\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2}$$
has a maximum error equal to $0.0150532\ldots$

Comment: thank you! nice trick